# How can I implement multivariate linear regression?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression, multivariate-testing

I have built a simple linear regressor below...

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0.0], [0.33], [0.66], [1.0]])
y = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]).T
w = np.random.random((1, 1))

for j in xrange(100000):
    a2 = np.dot(x, w) + 1
    w += x.T.dot((y - a2))
print(a2)
```

Now here is my attempt at developing it to include multivariate data...

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0.0], [0.33], [0.66], [1.0]])
x2 = np.array([[0.0], [0.33], [0.66], [1.0]])
y = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]).T
w = np.random.random((1, 1))

for j in xrange(100000):
    mx = np.dot(x, w) + np.dot(x2, w)
    w += (np.sum(x, x2)).T.dot((y - a2))
print(mx)
```

It seems to not be letting me add together the x and x2 arrays. Also the model yielded infinite values before hand. Please give me some pointers? Just numpy and python please no scikit learn as the true way to learn machine learning is from scratch really. Feel free to change the data in x and y arrays. Bonus points for plotting data and regression line with matplotlib! If the results are bad then of course it doesn’t matter because it’s linear regression after all. Thanks again

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
"It's not really working" is not a problem specification.

Comment: Um, I guess it depends what you mean "by scratch" but using just numpy the closed-form ordinary-least-squares is something like `betas = np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)` see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Least-squares_estimation_and_related_techniques).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga was that code you just gave me the update rule for the weights, or mx?

Comment: what's "mx"? It's for the betas, i.e. it is the OLS estimate for the coefficients. Update rule? Are you trying to implement gradient descent or something? You need to be way more specific about what you are trying to do here...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga okay I put that into the project, it seems to be valid, what’s the update rule for the weight?

Comment: ... there is no update rule. Again, what exactly are you talking about? What weights? That is the closed-form OLS estimator. Again, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Least-squares_estimation_and_related_techniques). I

Comment: Yes thank you! This was very helpful :)) @sera

Comment: @sera not high enough reputation haha

Comment: Hey, i input exactly what you wrote and I got an error. “w+= np.... ValueError: non broadcastable output operand with shape (1,2) doesn’t match the broadcast shape (2,2). How come yours works?? I’m using python 2 btw... @sera

Comment: yes it is true. I just noticed that. I was using a2 matrix. The weight w, how should me updated ?

Comment: The dimensions of concatenation function is 2,4 and y-mx is 4,2. Looks like a transposition issue. I used x.shape to get the dimensions @sera

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is **numpy concatenate** function:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0.0], [0.33], [0.66], [1.0]])
x2 = np.array([[0.0], [0.33], [0.66], [1.0]])
y = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]).T
w = np.random.random((1, 2))

x_all = np.concatenate((x,x2),axis = 1)

for j in xrange(100):
    mx = np.dot(x_all, w.T)
    w += (x_all.T.dot((y - mx))).T

print(mx)
```

This works but i am not sure that the way that the weights are updated is correct.

Some examples of linear regression from scratch can be found here:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-simple-linear-regression-scratch-python/

https://mubaris.com/2017-09-28/linear-regression-from-scratch

Comment: I got NAN results but at least there are no errors. Thank you for your efforts, you are truly awesome

Comment: If you reduce the loop to 100 as i did in my code, you get values !!